# Safe to pass empty variables by value, when they have no definition?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, extern, one-definition-rule

If I pass an empty variable by value, even though it has no definition, is it safe and compliant?

I came across this issue while working on code, overloading `|`, to make this print the contents of the vector `v`:

```
v | print; // prints the vector v
```

The code I present here works for me with `g++` and `clang`, even though `print` is an `extern` variable with no linkage, but I wonder if I'm pushing the standard too far. This is for c++11/c++14, I guess this is solved in c++17 with `inline` variables?

First, my initial code. The goal is to allow things like `v|print` to print a vector. I have bigger goals too, related to ranges, but I'll focus on this tiny example here

```
struct print_tag_t {};

print_tag_t print;

void operator| (std::vector<int> & x, decltype(print) ) {
    for(auto elem : x) {
        std::cout << elem << '\n';
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int>  v{2,3,5,7};
    v | print;
}
```

### Moving this to a header

If I move this into a header, I can make the `operator|` overload as `inline`. But what about `print`? I have found that I can make it `extern` to avoid the linker error about duplicate symbols

```
// print.hh
struct print_tag_t {};

extern  // extern, as I can't use inline on a variable
print_tag_t print;

inline
void operator| (std::vector<int> & x, decltype(print) ) {
    for(auto elem : x) {
        std::cout << elem << '\n';
    }
}
```

This works for me. Somehow, even though `print` has no definition, I can do `v|print`. I guess it's because it's empty and therefore there is no value to inspect and therefore it never needs an address.

Are compilers required to allow my `v|print` example to work? Where, to clarify, `print` is `extern` and hasn't been given any definition?

Comment: Interesting idea. How about `const struct print_tag_t {} print;` in your header file? No problem with multiple definitions.
`

Comment: But the linker should be complaining about the non-existence of "print_tag_t print;", or is that still in the cpp file? It would need to be somewhere, though you could do as suggested above, or use an anonymous namespace.
Personally, when I need a token like this I declare an enum with 1 value, and use the value asa unique typed instance.

Comment: @GemTaylor, neither compiler complains about that. And I don't have that in any cpp file. But yes, it suggests g++ and clang are being a little lenient with me

Comment: I suspect you are just being lucky with high optimisation settings.
Though it is very difficult to make gcc be completely dumb, try -fno-inline ?

Comment: You can wrap `print` declaration in an anonymous namespace, so it is local to each translation unit, or declare it new-age `inline` or old-school `static`.

Comment: The more usual thing to do here is to use an enum, e.g. `enum actions { print };`  and then overload for `enum actions` and you do not have to worry about the linkage issue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Are compilers required to allow my `v|print` example to work? Where, to clarify, print is `extern` and hasn't been given any definition?

No. You are odr-using `print` (you're invoking an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion that doesn't yield a constant expression), which means you need a definition for `print`. However, this is one of the categories of error that are ill-formed, no diagnostic required. And since the code in question doesn't take the address of `print` anywhere, it's likely that the compiler will emit code that will not require such a definition, and hence the linker will be happy about it too. Typically, it will Just Work™.

A better solution would be to simply change the declaration to make `print` `constexpr`:

```
constexpr print_tag_t print{};
```

Now, `v | print` wouldn't odr-use `print` (since the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion would now be a constant expression), so no definition is even necessary, so the program is well-formed.

Comment: @geza The original question had mixed up linkage and definition, and the answer was mostly about linkage. With T.C.'s edit, the question makes more sense, and I edited the answer to reflect the better wording of the question.

Comment: @ArneVogel No, that *definitely* odr-uses `print`. Now we're taking its address, so it *needs* a definition!

Comment: D'oh! You're right. I was confusing this with complete vs. incomplete type.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid That was T.C. I just added [tag:C++]